# ScrollView with ListView not working correctly in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, scrollview

I am learning android application development where I have to display content and related trailers.
In order to display text content I have used `ScrollView` but according to documentation `ScrollView` does not work properly.
I tried to fix it using `LinearLayout` which is working fine in portrait mode but not in landscape. I have attached image to explain it visually.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/title"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="421dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/releaseDate"
                    android:text="text"


                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_below="@id/releaseDate"
                    android:id="@+id/voteAverage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text2"
                    />



                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/plotSynopsis"

            android:text="@string/plot_synopsis"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />


            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/overView"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:padding="@dimen/abc_text_size_body_2_material" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Trailers:"
                android:id="@+id/trailersView"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="92dp"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_list_view" />
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some bottom portion is not scrollable in landscape, is that your problem?

Comment: yes it is. As bottom portion have list view to show trailer links @Masum

Comment: Your description header use as listview header instead of scrollview.

Comment: But plot synopsis is not part of the list and restricting it to list will restrict future modifications.Any other or standard solution for this problem @Masum

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes scroll view not working fine with listview you can use recyclerview on the place of listview that will be working fine and scroll smoothly.



 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_grid_images"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text_recent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```